# How can I stop Kotlin creating multiple overloaded Java methods out of one Kotlin function with optional parameters

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a function with annotations like that in my code:

```
@When("^trying to login or register with email address \"([^\"]*)\"$")
fun whenLoginOrRegister(email: String? = null) {
    email?.let { user.email = it }
    loginViewModel.whenLoggingIn()
}
```

What Kotlin does here is that it creates two or more overloads of the function depending on the number of optional parameters. How can I force Kotlin to just create one method instead of multiple? The optimum would be to just have one method which simply accepts `null`.

Background: I use Cucumber and it searches for these annotated functions by means of reflexion. But two functions with the same annotation lead to an exception as there are no ambiguities allowed. If I can't force Kotlin to create multiple methods, maybe there is a different workaround that can help in this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For such a function, if you don't use the `@JvmOverloads` annotation, Kotlin creates exactly two methods, regarding of the number of optional parameters. One method has the regular signature, and another one additionally accepts a bit mask of parameters that have been passed. There is no way to avoid creating multiple methods.

What I would do in this case is simply create two separate functions, "when trying to login or register without email" and "when trying to login or register with email address <email>".